# How can someone on a gluten free diet fulfill the mitzvah of eating challah on Shabbat?

Tags: challah-shabbat-bread

I have a relative who has a list of food ilnesses including egg, nut, wheat, soy and gluten allergies. As far as I know, he cannot eat anything that has the bracha "hamotzi". How can he fulfill the mitzvah of eating challah during the Shabbat meal? (FYI - He does say the full "Birkat Hamazon", relying on the fact that he is "satisfied".)

Comment: If he can't eat it then he can't do the Mitzva. Oh well.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Is eating Challah on Shabbat a requirement? If not, it wouldn't matter. If yes, I'm looking for alternatives, if there are any.

Comment: got it http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28502/759

Comment: @DanF, you're the one who first said it is a Mitzvah.

Comment: Mitzvot have many classifications, as you know. E.g. on Shabbat, MUST make Kiddush, but one is not forced to sing zemirot, though it is a mitzvah to eat both meat and fish, though one is not forced to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He can use oat bread which is [gluten-free](http://www.cureceliacdisease.org/archives/faq/do-oats-contain-gluten) and is biologically unrelated to wheat or barley.

Not all poskim consider oats to be hamotzi (that's its own question) so you should mention to your relative to ask his rabbi. As DoubleAA pointed out, he would probably prefer to use oat matza instead of attempting to eat oat-bread.

Answer (score 12):

There is no obligation to eat any food on Shabbat which harms you or is painful, even if that means fasting completely (OC 288:2). I obviously don't know your friend's medical details, but if there is nothing he is allowed to eat then he is simply exempt.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Moshe Sternbuch in his Teshuvos V'Hanhagos 7:23 writes that bread without gluten is a mezonos,and a bracha mein shalosh is said after eating it,even if one is koveah a seuda on it. However,this is only talking about a healthy person. He says a Choleh who cannot eat gluten should wash,make hamotzi and bentch on such bread since for such a person its considered pas. CYLOR for lmaaseh.

Conclusion: eat gluten free challah.

Comment: What may play into this mix is that there is a general rule that when *pat haba bekisnin* is eaten as a meal, then one would wash and say *hamotzi*. If you can link the above, I'd appreciate it. I'd like to read his reasoning that suggests why the lack of gluten overrides this other rule. Unless this is something that you can locate and add into the above. I may ask a "side question" as to if *pat haba bekisnin* may be used for Kiddush.

Comment: @DanF, it is not a link,but from his new volume,I am not sure if it's correct to post a pic of teshuva,since it brand new

Comment: Interesting. he claims gluten free bread (even from wheat) is like Isat Klavim that isn't normal bread, but for people that that's their bread it is considered bread since there's enough of them that exist to not be Batla Daatam. But see later 27:4 where he says that any part of wheat has a Din of wheat even if chemically separated. He'd say "pat" is different but that's not obvious I think.

Comment: It's def a chiddush

Comment: Also is there such a thing a gluten free wheat bread

Answer (score 0):

You can drink enough wine or grape juice to constitute a seudah.  I do this regularly at a kiddush if there is nothing there without sugar in it (pretty common, actually).

Here is a decent article specifically about your question, which also supports my answer.

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/835592/jewish/My-Doctor-Ordered-Me-Off-Challah.htm

Comment: I think you are mixing up two different notions of "seudah".