# What is the blessing on cricket bread?

Tags: blessing, food, bread

[This](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/nov/23/anyone-for-crickets-bread-made-insect-finnish-bakery-fazer) recent article speaks of commercially available bread made from ground crickets. To clarify, crickets are ground into flour and used in some combination with wheat flour.
Now, to the best of my understanding ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosher_locust)), such bread could potentially be kosher.

But what would be the blessing on this bread? I mean, would it qualify as bread? Or would it be Mezonos, or even Shehakol?

I am particularly interested to find out whether, potentially, considering its higher protein content, health benefits and environmental considerations, cricket bread could become the standard staple bread, or whether we would necessarily need strictly grain-based bread for all situations when we want Hamotzi (e.g. the [requirement to eat bread on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28502/17315))?

Comment: I don't see why this is different from a hamburger

Comment: I've never heard of this. But, I'd imagine this must be the loudest bread anyone would ever eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mezonot or Hamotsi are for some kind of specially valuable "fruits of the earth". Assuming that cricket is a pure grasshopper, the beracha is shehakol.

Mishna Berachot 6:3 (nusach Harambam). On foods who don't grow from the ground, one blesses "shehakol",   on vinegar, on immature dates, on Govai, one says ""shehakol" (this 3 first in the list are shehakol for a different reason not treated in this answer)), (now example of the rule with which the Mishna started) on milk, on cheese, on eggs, one blesses shehakol", on vinegar, on 
"

> על דבר שאין גידוליו מן הארץ אומר שהכל נהיה בדברו על החומץ ועל הגובאי ועל הנובלות הוא אומר שהכל נהיה בדברו ועל החלב ועל הגבינה ועל הביצים הוא אומר שהכל נהיה בדברו .

The Govai, a kind of kosher grasshopper, his blessing is shehakol.

A personal remez, Chalav, Gevina, Betsim (lichora not a chiddush, following the rule they obviously need shehakol), Initials is חגב

ח__לב

ג__בינה

ב__יצים

This is a remez what is Govai.

The cricket flour has (even a majority of) cereals, so, assuming that it's kosher, the blessing is mezonot or Hamotsi depending if we make cakes or bread.

Comment: "depending if we make cakes or bread" - careful! You're somewhat alluding to the *pat haba bikisnin* zone which is quite complex. In those areas, even "cakes" can require *hamotzi* depending on the situation.

Comment: DanF I know but it's not the topic. If you know a better word, please tell me

Comment: A literal translation of *pat haba bekisnin* wouldn't do it, here. Leave it the way it is, for now, unless OP asks for elaboration.

Comment: This is a nice answer showing that the bracha on kosher grasshoppers is shehakol. But the actual answer to the question, regarding the blessing which would be made on a mixture of crickets and grain, is only mentioned in your last sentence. How do you know this would be even mezonos? Perhaps, as DoubleAA mentioned, it's more similar to a hamburger and would still be shehakol? Could you explain, and perhaps source, your answer?

Comment: In a hamburger I'm not sure that the beracha is shehakol